# keyup event does not set event shiftKey JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

The function onkeyup  works fine with all the characters when both SHIFT key and character are pressed , or keeping SHIFT key pressed and key up the character, but my problem happens when key up the SHIFT key before the character . The value returned is with lowercase characters . So for example if I key up SHIFT and press a, 'a' is returned but not 'A' .

So my question is how do to  SHIFT key is being keyup . I've tried the following check but this didn't work :

```
pass_input_obj[i]['input'].onkeyup = function(event) {`enter code here`
    if(event.key == "Process") {
        if(event.code.includes("Shift")) keypressed= "Shift";
     } else
          keypressed= event.key; 


if(keypressed == "Shift" || (event.code && event.code.includes("Shift"))) shiftclicked = false;

if(!isSpecialKey(keypressed) && !crtlclicked){
    Capletter = keypressed;

if(shiftclicked == true){
    Capletter = keypressed.toUpperCase();
}
}
```

Comment: May beI'm  on not up to date, I think you need the key code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got clear all your needs. I assume you want to press and release 'Shift' button and click any other character. That character then should be capitalized.

Here is my way of implementing it

```js
var inputEl = document.getElementById('txt');
var isPrevShiftClicked = false;
inputEl.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if(isPrevShiftClicked) {
    inputEl.value = inputEl.value.slice(0, inputEl.value.length - 1) + inputEl.value.charAt([inputEl.value.length - 1]).toUpperCase();
  }
  isPrevShiftClicked = event.keyCode === 16;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```